# removing characters from field in MS Access database table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

Using MS Access 2010.
I have a field in a table that contains windows path names surrounded by quotes, like this

```
"C:\My Documents\Photos\img1.jpg"
"C:\My Documents\Photos\products\gizmo.jpg"
"C:\My Documents\Photos\img5.jpg"
```

and so on.

I need to get rid of the quotes so the column looks like this:

```
C:\My Documents\Photos\img1.jpg
C:\My Documents\Photos\products\gizmo.jpg
C:\My Documents\Photos\img5.jpg
```

Is there a way to write an update query to do this?
OR a better way to do it altogether?

Answer (score 9):

If you will be doing this from within an Access session, using Access 2000 or later, you can use the `Replace()` function in an update query to remove the quotes.  Remove would mean replace them with an empty string.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET path_field = Replace(path_field, '"', '');
```

If any of those path strings could include quotes *within* them (yuck!), consider the `Mid()` function ... ask it to start at the 2nd character (skipping the lead quote), and return the number of characters equivalent to `Len(path_field) - 2`

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET path_field = Mid(path_field, 2, Len(path_field) - 2);
```

Either way, you may want to include a WHERE clause to ignore rows without `path_field` values.

```
WHERE Len(path_field) > 0
```

And if you must do this again when new data is added, use a different WHERE clause to ensure you UPDATE only those rows whose `path_field` values start and end with quotes.

```
WHERE path_field Like '"*"'
```

That was using the * wild card for Access' default ANSI 89 mode.  If you will do this from ADO (ANSI 92 mode), use the % wild card.

```
WHERE path_field Like '"%"'
```

... or use `ALike` and the % wild card with either mode.

```
WHERE path_field ALike '"%"'
```

Comment: Aside: I see you have joined the, em, exclusive club. Congratulations :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution with `REPLACE` already mentioned by others works, but removes ALL quotes, even if they are in the middle of the string.

If you only want to remove quotes at the beginning or at the end, but leave quotes in the middle of the string as they are, you can do it with the following two queries:

Remove first character if it's a quote:

```
update YourTable
set YourField = right(YourField, len(YourField) - 1)
where left(YourField, 1) = '"'
```

Remove last character if it's a quote:

```
update YourTable
set YourTable = left(YourField, len(YourField) - 1)
where right(YourField, 1) = '"'
```

Comment: This is probably the best bet since it accounts for quote characters being in the middle of the string.  I don't think I have any of those but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: QUESTION - knowing YourTable, YourField are whatever my field & table names are, why do you use set YourField = ..... when removing the left char but use set location = ... when removing the right char?

Comment: @maneesha: Oops..."location" is a typo, I just corrected it in my answer. I was too lazy to create a new table to test my queries, so I used an existing one, with a column named "location". When I copied the query from Access in my answer here, I simply forgot to replace one "location" :-)

Comment: @HansUp: It depends :-) One one hand, my solution has two queries and yours has only one. On the other hand, my solution works better when there's only one quote at the beginning **or** the end. But I don't think that's the case here (the question sounds like there are always quotes in both places), so your answer is more elegant.

Comment: I see your points.  This would be a whole lot simpler if the questioners provided sample data which include all the variations they need handled.  :-0

Answer (score 0):

To make this a permanent change, you might run an update query that looked something like this:

```
UPDATE [Your Table]
SET [Your Table].[Your Field] = Replace([Your Table].[Your Field],"""","")
```

This will get rid of *all* quotes, even if they aren't at the beginning or end.  Post back if that's not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column name is MyColumn and table name is MyTable, you can use this sql to update your data to get rid of quotes.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn,'"','')
```