# Access: How to replace mm/dd/yyyy with mm/yyyy with an unknown position within a string?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with data that looks like the sample below. Some lines contain a date in mm/dd/yyyy format but I need to remove the /dd part so that it ends up in mm/yyyy or m/yyyy without changing any of the other values. It also has to stay a string. In the desired output, I put ** at the beginning and end of the values that I modified just as a reference point.

From what I have gathered, REPLACE won't work because you'd have to modify it 31 times to account for every day range possible.

```
EXPRESSION
07/2021
17.52082 X M/D 5.000000 EXP B/1.3000 6.860641
X X M/D 84.169 IMU EXP 5.000000
7/2023
0.182849 X B/D 5.000000 EXP B/1.30000 6/23/2011 8.931606
X X B/D 0.073 IMU EXP 5.000000
04/08/2011 45.70 11*0 M#
04/2011 45.70 11*0 M#
07/2023 3*0 #
01/31/2021 3*0 #
```

Desired output

```
07/2021
17.52082 X M/D 5.000000 EXP B/1.3000 6.860641
X X M/D 84.169 IMU EXP 5.000000
7/2023
0.182849 X B/D 5.000000 EXP B/1.30000 **6/2011** 8.931606
X X B/D 0.073 IMU EXP 5.000000
**04/2011 45.70 11*0 M#**
04/2011 45.70 11*0 M#
07/2023 3*0 #
**01/2021 3*0 #**
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10249929

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing characters from field in MS Access database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249929/removing-characters-from-field-in-ms-access-database-table)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a simple replace. I'd look at regex, lot of examples can be found by "vba regex", see usage of CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"). If it needs to be SQL then you can write your VBA function and use it in UPDATE SQL query

Comment: See my 2nd code snip below - it a bit convoluted - but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
Public Function dConv(vIn As Variant) As String

        Dim strOut     As String
        
        If IsNull(vIn) Then
           dConv = ""
           Exit Function
        End If
        
        Dim v          As Variant
        v = Split(vIn, "/")
        
        If UBound(v) >= 2 Then
           ' whole date, get just mm/yyyy
           strOut = Format(vIn, "mm\/yyyy")
        Else
        ' only 1 /, don't change
           strOut = vIn
        End If
        
        dConv = strOut
        
End Function
```

So,

```
? dconv("02/2021")  ->> 02/2021
? dConv("02/24/2021") --> 02/2021
```

And you can even use the above function in a query.

```
SELECT ID, InvoiceNumber, IvDate, dConv([IvDate]) as NDate from tblCustomers
```

Now, above will conver the date for you. But, as noted, you  NOW need to pluck out a date from the string. That's more difficult.

But, this does seem to work:

```
  Public Function dConv2(vIn As Variant) As String
  
           Dim strOut     As String
           
           If IsNull(vIn) Then
              dConv2 = ""
              Exit Function
           End If
           
           Dim v          As Variant
           v = Split(vIn, " ")
           
           Dim s As Variant
           Dim s2 As Variant
           
           Dim v2         As Variant
           
           For Each s In v
              v2 = Split(s, "/")
              If UBound(v2) = 2 Then
                 ' this looks to be a date
                 strOut = Format(s, "mm\/yyyy")
              Else
                 If UBound(v2) = 1 Then
                    If Len(v2(1)) = 4 Then
                        If IsNumeric(v2(1)) Then
                             strOut = s
                        End If
                    End If
                 End If
              End If
           Next
           
           If strOut <> "" Then
              dConv2 = strOut
           Else
              dConv2 = vIn
           End If
           
  End Function
```